# How to parse a ordered txt file

Tags: c#, parsing

I have a text file below. I am trying to parse the text file and store the values, but I am not sure what the best approach is. I currently have it read line by line and used regex find certain text in the file. I want to store the variables in this fashion. How would I do this?

```
-Table
     |-Element # (iteration)
                           |-Attribute Name
                           |-Attribute Value
-Table
     |-Element # (iteration)
                           |-Attribute Name
                           |-Attribute Value
```

`Table:FXsegments
Element FXsegment:
Attribute version:910004000
Attribute sbdate:1975-08-20
Attribute sbdate-type:YMD
Attribute XMLversion:V_R072518_1514
Attribute XMLcrc:1970222190
Attribute reptypes:I
Attribute scripts:NOSCRIPT
Element FXsegment:
Attribute first:JAYESM
Attribute middle:W
Attribute last:CHOKSI
Attribute suffix:SR
Attribute daterep:2018-10-17
Attribute daterep-type:YMD
Attribute fraud:N
Attribute fileno:F
Attribute filehit:1
Table:PXsegments
Element PXsegment:
Attribute product-code:07000
Attribute fileno:1
Attribute filehit:
Attribute version:0
Attribute country:1
Attribute language:1`
`

```
                while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Regex regexSegName = new Regex(".*FXsegments.*|.*PXsegments.*;
                Match matchSegName = regexSegName.Match(line);
                if (matchSegName.Success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
                Regex regexSegNameITR = new Regex("Element .*");
                Match matchSegNameITR = regexSegNameITR.Match(line);
                if (matchSegNameITR.Success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
                Regex regexSegAttr= new Regex("Attribute .*");
                Match matchSegAttr = regexSegAttr.Match(line);
                if (matchSegAttr.Success)
                {

                    string attributeLine = Regex.Replace(line, "Attribute ", "");
                    string[] parsed = attributeLine.Split(':');
                    Console.WriteLine(parsed[0] + " " + parsed[1]);
                }
            }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? You want to rewrite the text file? Or do you want to store the data somewhere else?

Comment: Sorry. I should've clarified. I am trying to write a loop that reads the text file line by line and store them in the way stated above. Not sure how to approach this and what  datatypes to use